# Fetch the 95th percentile response time and corresponding name from the html response in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Response to my get request is a html response type and I want to fetch all name and its 95th percentile response time from the html response.

I am using `jsdom` for achieving this.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

JSDOM.fromURL(`http://localhost.report:8086/63cfe8b9-e62c-57fa-b2b0-3cf28c621b6c/1676005525/report.html`).then(dom => {
  console.log(dom.serialize());
});
```

The above URL has following section,

[image]

[image]

And I want to fetch the 95th percentile response time from both the section and their name as well. How to achieve this in NodeJS? (Have added the html file as well)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Test Report for BaselineTest.py
  </title>
  <link href="../static/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <style>
   body {
            background: #173529;
        }
        .container {
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #ecf3ee;
        }

        .info span {
            color: #b3c3bc;
        }

        .charts-container .chart {
            width: 100%;
            height: 350px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .download {
            float: right;
        }

        .download a {
            color: #00ca5a;
        }
        
        /* tables.css */
table.stats {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #11251c;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
table.stats thead {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #a9c5ba;
}
table.stats thead tr {
  background: #11251c;
}
table.stats thead tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #11251c;
}
table.stats thead tr:hover {
  background: #11251c;
}
table.stats thead th {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
table.stats thead th.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table.stats thead th[data-sortkey] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
table.stats tr:hover {
  background: #1d4434;
}
table.stats tr td, table.stats tr th {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
table.stats tr td:first-child, table.stats tr th:first-child {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
table.stats tr td:last-child, table.stats tr th:last-child {
  padding-right: 16px;
}
table.stats tr td.numeric, table.stats tr th.numeric {
  text-align: right;
}
table.stats tr td {
  max-width: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  table.stats tr td {
    max-width: 350px;
  }
}
table.stats tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #153126;
}
table.stats tr:nth-child(even):hover {
  background: #1d4434;
}
table.stats tr.total {
  background: #11251c;
}
table.stats tr.total td {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=tables.css.map */
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="http://localhost:8086/TestReports/Perf/PERF_BaselineTest/63cfe8b9-e62c-57fa-b2b0-3cf28c621b6c/1676005525/report.htm" style="color: #d0eca7">
   test-plan
  </a>
  <div class="container" id="0">
   <h1>
    BaselineTest Test Report
    - 0
   </h1>
   <div class="info">
    <p>
     During:
     <span class="l10n datetime">
      2023-02-10 05:02:21
     </span>
     -
     <span class="l10n datetime">
      2023-02-10 05:03:17
     </span>
    </p>
    <p>
     Target Host:
     <span>
      http://localhost.report:8086
     </span>
    </p>
    <p>
     Script:
     <span>
      BaselineTest.py
     </span>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="requests">
    <h2>
     Request Statistics
    </h2>
    <table class="stats">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="sortable">
        Method
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Name
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        # Requests
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        # Fails
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Average (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Min (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Max (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Average size (bytes)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        RPS
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Failures/s
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        POST
       </td>
       <td>
        /api/v1/orders
       </td>
       <td>
        12
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        27
       </td>
       <td>
        17
       </td>
       <td>
        52
       </td>
       <td>
        516
       </td>
       <td>
        0.2
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total">
       <td>
       </td>
       <td>
        Aggregated
       </td>
       <td>
        12
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        27
       </td>
       <td>
        17
       </td>
       <td>
        52
       </td>
       <td>
        516
       </td>
       <td>
        0.2
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <div class="responses">
    <h2>
     Response Time Statistics
    </h2>
    <table class="stats">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="sortable">
        Method
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Name
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        50%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        60%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        70%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        80%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        90%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        95%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        99%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        100%ile (ms)
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        POST
       </td>
       <td>
        /api/v1/orders
       </td>
       <td>
        25
       </td>
       <td>
        27
       </td>
       <td>
        27
       </td>
       <td>
        35
       </td>
       <td>
        44
       </td>
       <td>
        53
       </td>
       <td>
        53
       </td>
       <td>
        53
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total">
       <td>
       </td>
       <td>
        Aggregated
       </td>
       <td>
        25
       </td>
       <td>
        27
       </td>
       <td>
        27
       </td>
       <td>
        35
       </td>
       <td>
        44
       </td>
       <td>
        53
       </td>
       <td>
        53
       </td>
       <td>
        53
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="container" id="1">
   <h1>
    BaselineTest Test Report
    - 1
   </h1>
   <div class="info">
    <p>
     During:
     <span class="l10n datetime">
      2023-02-10 05:03:23
     </span>
     -
     <span class="l10n datetime">
      2023-02-10 05:05:22
     </span>
    </p>
    <p>
     Target Host:
     <span>
      http://localhost.report:8086
     </span>
    </p>
    <p>
     Script:
     <span>
      BaselineTest.py
     </span>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="requests">
    <h2>
     Request Statistics
    </h2>
    <table class="stats">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="sortable">
        Method
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Name
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        # Requests
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        # Fails
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Average (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Min (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Max (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Average size (bytes)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        RPS
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Failures/s
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-Close
       </td>
       <td>
        5
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        66
       </td>
       <td>
        59
       </td>
       <td>
        73
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-NavProfitLosses
       </td>
       <td>
        4
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        78
       </td>
       <td>
        71
       </td>
       <td>
        90
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-NavReport
       </td>
       <td>
        4
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        82
       </td>
       <td>
        73
       </td>
       <td>
        104
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-Open
       </td>
       <td>
        7
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        148
       </td>
       <td>
        69
       </td>
       <td>
        498
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.1
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-PendingPayable
       </td>
       <td>
        8
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        84
       </td>
       <td>
        37
       </td>
       <td>
        170
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.1
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-Position
       </td>
       <td>
        2
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        151
       </td>
       <td>
        89
       </td>
       <td>
        212
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        Positions Report
       </td>
       <td>
        7
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        166
       </td>
       <td>
        90
       </td>
       <td>
        296
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.1
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total">
       <td>
       </td>
       <td>
        Aggregated
       </td>
       <td>
        37
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        112
       </td>
       <td>
        37
       </td>
       <td>
        498
       </td>
       <td>
        0
       </td>
       <td>
        0.3
       </td>
       <td>
        0.0
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <div class="responses">
    <h2>
     Response Time Statistics
    </h2>
    <table class="stats">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="sortable">
        Method
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        Name
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        50%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        60%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        70%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        80%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        90%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        95%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        99%ile (ms)
       </th>
       <th class="sortable">
        100%ile (ms)
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-Close
       </td>
       <td>
        66
       </td>
       <td>
        72
       </td>
       <td>
        72
       </td>
       <td>
        74
       </td>
       <td>
        74
       </td>
       <td>
        74
       </td>
       <td>
        74
       </td>
       <td>
        74
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-NavProfitLosses
       </td>
       <td>
        78
       </td>
       <td>
        78
       </td>
       <td>
        78
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-NavReport
       </td>
       <td>
        76
       </td>
       <td>
        76
       </td>
       <td>
        76
       </td>
       <td>
        100
       </td>
       <td>
        100
       </td>
       <td>
        100
       </td>
       <td>
        100
       </td>
       <td>
        100
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-Open
       </td>
       <td>
        81
       </td>
       <td>
        82
       </td>
       <td>
        82
       </td>
       <td>
        160
       </td>
       <td>
        500
       </td>
       <td>
        500
       </td>
       <td>
        500
       </td>
       <td>
        500
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-PendingPayable
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        92
       </td>
       <td>
        150
       </td>
       <td>
        170
       </td>
       <td>
        170
       </td>
       <td>
        170
       </td>
       <td>
        170
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        AccReport-Position
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        GET
       </td>
       <td>
        Positions Report
       </td>
       <td>
        110
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        280
       </td>
       <td>
        300
       </td>
       <td>
        300
       </td>
       <td>
        300
       </td>
       <td>
        300
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total">
       <td>
       </td>
       <td>
        Aggregated
       </td>
       <td>
        81
       </td>
       <td>
        91
       </td>
       <td>
        93
       </td>
       <td>
        150
       </td>
       <td>
        210
       </td>
       <td>
        300
       </td>
       <td>
        500
       </td>
       <td>
        500
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <script>
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('datetime');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var epoch = Date.parse(elements[i].innerHTML + ' UTC')
                var dt = new Date(epoch);
                elements[i].innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
            }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```